# Standardize data with diffent number of dimensions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe different in the dimension of each row. As I acknowledge, I think that I should make the number of row dimensions equal to each other. So I performed sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler on the data before I can use any data analysis method.

```
0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8 
0.00    5.00    16.00   13.00   18.00   34.00   33.00   24.00   19.00
0.00    6.00    17.00   27.00   9.00    7.00    0.00    nan     nan
0.00    5.00    16.00   12.00   14.00   15.00   0.00    nan     nan 
0.00    8.00    0.00    nan     nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
0.00    5.00    10.00   32.00   17.00   24.00   25.00   26.00   10.00
0.00    5.00    14.00   16.00   17.00   19.00   10.00   6.00    0.00
0.00    8.00    8.00    15.00   24.00   10.00   9.00    0.00    nan
0.00    6.00    21.00   33.00   38.00   22.00   0.00    nan     nan
0.00    9.00    8.00    9.00    14.00   13.00   12.00   13.00   9.00
```

I used this code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_df = StandardScaler()
df = sc_df.fit_transform(df)
```

But it has the error: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'), since my data contain NaN value.

What should I do to perform Data Analysis on this data?

Edit: the empty cell is not noise, they are the characteristic of each row.

Comment: You need to decide what to do with missing data, your options are drop the rows, fill them with the column-wise mean so it doesn't skew the scaling or some other nominal value like 0 or -1

Comment: Following on what EdChum says, you can use `sc_df.fit_transform(df.fillna(0))` if you want to _fill_ the NaNs with 0, or some other ordinal. Or you can use `sc_df.fit_transform(df.dropna())` to get rid of rows with NaNs entirely.

Comment: I forgot to mention that they are meant to be empty value. I tried to fill them with 0, but some guys said that it's wrong to do so

Comment: in addition, you can add columns that contain indicators of missing data. In that case, (maybe after introducing interaction terms) a model can learn to decide, what to do with missing data.

Comment: Is the missing data tantamount to noise, that you can just get rid of it and be left with rows of full data?

Comment: *if* it makes sense to replace nan with -1 then `sc_df.fit_transform(df.where(df.notnull(), -1))`

Comment: (Looking at your edit) We don't know what you want... you can only figure out what you want and ask for help.

Comment: The missing data row is not noise, the difference in the number of dimensions are their characteristic. I just don't know how to perform data analysis this data without making them equal in dimensions

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace the 'NaN' values with a number.

To replace the NaN value, use:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

You can change the 0 to any other number that you want to replace NaN with.
After this you can apply scaling.